# PasswordReset no envia el email Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy utilizando las clases de PasswordReset, funcionan bien, pero el problema es que no se manda el email, aparece en consola y por eso puedo entrar.

Que configuraciones se deben hacer?

Lei en un post que son estas, pero no funcionan:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'cabralvende.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'admin123'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'lucas'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@cabralvende.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@cabralvende.com'
```

urls.py

```
path(
    route='me/password_reset/',
    view=auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_done')),
    name='password_reset'
),

path(
    route='me/password_reset/done/',
    view=auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_done'
),

re_path(
    route='reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/',
    view=auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(success_url = reverse_lazy('users:password_reset_complete')),
    name='password_reset_confirm'
),

path(
    route='reset/done/',
    view=auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_complete'
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu configuración en `settings.py` esta mal cambia

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

esto como dice imprime el mail en consola por el defualt

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

el cual se envia a traves de un STMP

Comment: Al hacer este cambio me salta el siguiente error:
ConnectionRefusedError at /users/me/password_reset/
[WinError 10061] No se puede establecer una conexión ya que el equipo de destino denegó expresamente dicha conexión

Comment: Eso es cuestión de tu host de emails, la forma mas sencilla es usar un servicio externo de SMTP tipo https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/django/ que tiene una version de prueba, en tu caso puede ser que las credenciales, el puerto o algo mas este mal.